# How to maintain visibility state of controls?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

ASP.NET MVC is stateless,

How to maintain visibility state of controls?

e.g. I have a button control
I hide the button control using jquery
Now when I post-back the button appears again

I wonder if there is any workaround for this.

Comment: This question is far to board...

Comment: I understand, but I have to manage this somehow, one way I found is `Using hiddent fields` like web forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using strongly typed view models this is one approach you could take.

Create a view model with a bool property to represent that a property is shown i.e.

**View Model**

```
public class AModel
{
    public bool IsShown { get; set; }
}
```

Render this as a hidden for in your view which will allow state to be passed to and from the server.

**View**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsShown)
```

In your javascript make sure you set the value of the hidden field with:

```
$('#IsShown').val(true);
```

or:

```
$('#IsShown').val(false);
```

This will allow the state of the shown control to be posted back.

Then make sure your javascript hides or displays the control by passing in the `IsShown` property. Please note the below needs to use your actual button id.

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
 $('#AButtonId').toggle(@Model.IsShown.ToString().ToLower());
});
```